# object.freeze on object method only. JavaScript

Tags: javascript, object, freeze

I'm wondering if there is a known way for freezing a method on an object in JavaScript. e.g.

```
var obj = {};
    obj.method = function(){};
    Object.freeze(obj.method);
```

Then `obj.method = function(){//New function};` wouldn't do anything.

Maybe this doesn't work because it's, strictly speaking, a function but was just wondering if anyone had any solutions that might do what I want.

Also, I am aware of the deepFreeze concept but am trying to avoid using that and adding a where clause to only freeze that object due to the fact that my object is actually very big so I don't want to loop through it.

Thanks.

Comment: [`Object.defineProperty()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty) allows you to make a property unchangeable.

Comment: `Object.freeze` is working strictly speaking: that is, prevents new properties from being added to it; prevents existing properties from being removed; and prevents existing properties, or their enumerability, configurability, or writability, from being changed. So `method` is now frozen. But you actually want to define only the property `method` on `obj` and as mentioned `definedProperty` is what you need. But without `freeze` you will still be able to do, for example, `obj.method.something = function () {};`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Then `obj.method = function(){//New function};` wouldn't do anything.

Yes, it's quite simple with Object.defineProperty.

```
Object.defineProperty(obj, 'method', {
   value: function() {/* ... */},
   enumerable: true, // will show in Object.keys and for..in loop
   configurable: false, // can't be deleted
   writable: false // can't be redefined
});
```

Comment: Thanks for everyone's answers. Going to go with Ginden's as it has a nice example included.